# Cant expand SVN revision with FishEye

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn, atlassian-fisheye

I installed Atlassian FishEye and connected it with a SVN repository which is running by VisualSVN Server.

FishEye scanned about 60% of the repository and then it gets stuck at this error:

```
Repository paused due to error com.cenqua.fisheye.rep.RepositoryClientException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Can't overwrite cause with org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: CRLF expected at end of chunk: -1/-1 svn: 
E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/java/!svn/vcc/default' java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: 
svn: E175002: CRLF expected at end of chunk: -1/-1 svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/java/!svn/vcc/default' org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: 
svn: E175002: CRLF expected at end of chunk: -1/-1 svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/java/!svn/vcc/default'
```

What could cause this problem and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found a solution. I raised the timeout of the VisualSVN server and it works now.